# Does Java HTTP connection pool have an eviction time? Can it be set?

Tags: java, http, caching, connection, persistent

Java HTTP connection pooling for persistent connections is described at
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html. However, there is no indication if connections are ever evicted from the cache if they are not reused, and if so, what is the timeout length.

The only reference to this I found were the following comments from http://www.java.net/forum/topic/performance/general-performance-discussion/reusing-socket-connections-httpurlconnection-0:

> "the keep alive sockets are subject to a timeout. If the server sends back a timeout in the HTTP header, then that timeout value is used. Otherwise, the timeout is only 5 seconds, after which the socket will not be reused [...]   Unfortuantely, you cannot set the timeout; it is hardwared in the bowels of the implementation."

If true, this would explain some odd behavior we are seeing, and I wrote a small test case that seems to confirm this. (Using Java 1.6.20 on Windows.)

Does anyone know of any documentation on this? Also, the comment is several years old. Is the timeout still hardcoded, or can it be set?

Comment: To be honest, whenever I have questions like this, I simply go to the source code. The bulk of the Java library source is available in src.zip, and if you want something even deeper, you can get an idea by digging in to the OpenJDK sources. If they're not documenting the semantics, then the source can be used to find out what is "really" happens, though obviously relying on undocumented aspects of the system can be dangerous if those assumptions are changed in a later release. But at least you "know" what's going one right now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds pretty logical. The documentation for network properties (outside the ones you can set through the main API) is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html). AFAICT the only thing you can set is whether or not to use keep-alive and how many connections to pool.

In Java 7 they're [apparently](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) only checked at startup. There's no note to that effect on the java 6 docs but I assume that must be a documentation oversight then. So in principle, to turn off keepalive you'd have to pass it on the command line as:

```
java -Dhttp.keepalive=false ...
```

Or to make the pool per host smaller:

```
java -Dhttp.maxConnections=1 ...
```

You could also try with `System.setProperty()` but that supposedly wouldn't work.

It would be interesting to know what problems this causes, perhaps there is a solution to be found somewhere?

Comment: It is not causing problems per se.  We were just seeing that http persistent connection pooling in our application not working for some sites but working fine for others.  However, it appears to be an indirect effect of our app combined with the 5 second eviction time. For some sites we make multiple HTTP requests very quickly, others there is a delay.  Not knowing about the timeout, we thought there might be network issues or something automatically closing connections.

Comment: @ghirschhorn Okay, I'm pretty sure it's this behaviour you're seeing. If you need more control it seems the only option is to use a raw socket, which involves a bit more work.